# Distribute one member amount to others within group

Tags: sql

I have the table (t) of sales channel cost for each year: CH = channel (bo = back office).

```
YYYY . CH   COST
=====+====+======
2022 . c1 .  20
2022 . c2 .  30
2022 . bo .  50
2023 . c1 .  25
2023 . c2 .  40
2023 . bo .  80
```

The cost of backoffice (CH = bo) should be distributed to other sales channels according to coefficients in distribution table (d):

```
CH . BO_PERC
===+========
c1 .   0.2    <- 20% from BO cost should be added to c1 channel cost (per year)
c2 .   0.4    <- 40% from BO cost should be added to c2 channel cost (per year)
```

The resulting table should look like:

```
YYYY . CH . COST
=====+====+=====
2022 . c1 .  30     <- 20 + 50*0.2
2022 . c2 .  50     <- 30 + 50*0.4
2023 . c1 .  41     <- 25 + 80*0.2
2023 . c2 .  72     <- 40 + 80*0.4
```

How to get the resulting table with yearly BO cost distributed to other channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on your table and column names. Aside from them being too short and non-descriptive, `BO_PERC` is actually wrong: it isn't stored as a percentage.

The following query outputs the expected results:

```sql
create table channel_costs(
  year smallint not null check(year between 1900 and 2200),
  channel varchar(2) not null,
  cost money not null check (cost > cast(0 as money))
);

insert into channel_costs(year, channel, cost) values
(2022, 'c1',  20),
(2022, 'c2',  30),
(2022, 'bo',  50),
(2023, 'c1',  25),
(2023, 'c2',  40),
(2023, 'bo',  80);

create table distribution(
  channel varchar(2) not null,
  backoffice_fraction real not null check(backoffice_fraction between 0 and 1)
);

insert into distribution(channel, backoffice_fraction) values
('c1', 0.2),
('c2', 0.4);

select front_costs.year,
       front_costs.channel,
       front_costs.cost + distribution.backoffice_fraction * back_costs.cost as cost
from channel_costs as front_costs
join channel_costs as back_costs on back_costs.year = front_costs.year
                                and back_costs.channel = 'bo'
                                and front_costs.channel <> 'bo'
join distribution on distribution.channel = front_costs.channel
order by front_costs.year, front_costs.channel;
```